# Can I use Missed Flight Cover to change the date of my ticket?

Tags: air-travel, insurance, easyjet

I would like to change the date of travel on my ticket. With EasyJet it costs much.

[image]

In fact £45 is more than the price of the ticket itself so getting a new tickets is cheaper. However, when I booked the ticket I have purchases a Missed Flight Cover.

[image]

Can I just go the airport and deliberately miss my flight and use that cover to get a ticket on the next flight? **which is the flight I wanted to change my ticket to in the first place**

Comment: Next available flight might not be the next flight if that is fully booked...

Comment: @MartinSmith I am fine with that, even a refund is ok, anything but £45 per passenger! I am not travelling alone

Comment: You can just get an other flight with the same payed fare

Comment: It depends on the exact insurance terms and the reasons of missing the flight, which are applicable.

Comment: And how much will it cost you if the next available flight isn't until the next day or even days later and you need to book a hotel?

Comment: You're actually trying to change the *date* of travel?  Note that the terms say you have to show up at the departure airport within 4 hours of the flight time, and will be put on the next flight, which in all probability would be the same day.  So that scheme won't get you a flight on a different date.

Comment: @NateEldredge some low-cost flights only leave once or twice per week, so it's feasible

Comment: Look for the fine print, they might have other terms which might disqualify you form doing this.

Comment: looks legit, it does say for ANY reason... did you end up trying it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official [Missed Flight Cover FAQ](http://www.easyjet.com/en/missed-flight-cover/faq) seems straightforward enough:

> 3) **What does Missed Flight Cover actually insure me for?**
>
> In the event you miss your flight you will be offered either:
>
> a) **A seat ... on the next available easyJet flight to the same destination**.
>
> ...
>
> 4) Are there any exclusions to the policy?
>
> There are no exclusions but there are 3 simple conditions should you wish to make a claim:
>
> a) **You must be at the airport within 4 hours after the scheduled
>   departure time** of your flight and the plane must depart.
>
> b) You must be in a "fit state to fly";
>
> ...
>
> c) You must tell the easyJet Sales Desk at the airport that you wish
>   to make a claim.
>
> ...
>
> 5) **Are there any circumstances that would prevent you from paying a claim under the policy?**  Yes, if you fail to follow one or more of
>   three conditions stated in Question 4.

So the answer is **yes**, you can do that. However you'll have to arrive at the airport within 4 hours of the plane departure to arrange for a replacement ticket.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the marketing blurb and the full FAQ both offer a second possibility - that you will be given a refund. And the terminology is such that thats the airlines choice, not the passengers.  So there is no guarantee you will be booked on a flight at all, just given your money back. The answer should be changed to "possibly".